# Wrong display resolutions with amdgpu drivers

Tags: arch-linux, display, resolution, amdgpu

After using EndeavourOS's Arch distro in my laptop, I decided to install the same distro in my main computer.

The computer has an AMD RX6600, and I figured out how to install the amdgpu drivers.
The problem comes when I try to start the computer and both of my monitors display resolutions of 640x480, even though they are 1366x768 and 1920x1080.

I found somewhere, that I had to add the kms service to the HOOKS section of the mkinitcpio.conf file, to make the amdgpu drivers run first than the xorg default ones, but that didn't help.

Im running out of answers on how to make it run, I just fell in love with Arch and I dont want to have to go back to Windows.